# updating many-to-many relationships in asp.net mvc2 using entity framework 4.0 problem

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

Can some one point out what I am doing wrong. I went through all related questioin on this site, but I think my problem is more with MYSQL, As the error mentioned.The problem is when I try to update a relationship between two tables using EF in asp.net mvc2.

I have these tables and I am using MYSQL.

Course

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| courseid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| coursename | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Faculty:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| facultyid | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstname | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname  | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I have this table to create the relationship

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| courseid  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| facultyid | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now when I want to associate a course to a faculty, both the course and faculty are existing, using the code below I got a MYSQL error: Below

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult AddCourse(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        //I made this static values for debuging
        Course course = scheduleEnt.Courses1.First(p => p.courseid == 5); //existing course
        Faculty faculty = scheduleEnt.Faculties1.First(p => p.facultyid == 1); //existing faculty
        faculty.courses.Add(course);
        UpdateModel(faculty);
        scheduleEnt.SaveChanges();//This is where the error generated

        var cc = 5;

        return RedirectToAction("AddCourse", new { cid = cc });
    }
```

This is the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT
     `course_faculty`.`courseid`,
     `course_faculty`.`facultyid`
' at line 1
```

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same issue, although I'm using EF1 (.net 3.5) and .net connector 6.3.6.0. What's strange is I've got other many-to-many relationships within the same project/edmx that are working without any problem. Trying to get to the bottom of it right now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out that the issue in my case was the fact the linking table enabling the n:m relationship didn't explicitly have a primary key set. So although the only two fields were both FKs, the DBA hadn't set them to be a primary key in their own right.

I found that if I looked within the source of the edmx under the ssdl section there were  elements that matched the error I was getting when trying to perform the update:

```
<EntitySet Name="x_map" EntityType="DBModel.Store.x_map" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="xxx" store:Name="x_map">
        <DefiningQuery>SELECT
  `xxx`.`xxx`, 
  `xxx`.`xxx`
  FROM `xxx` AS `xxx`</DefiningQuery>
      </EntitySet>
```

And then above the defining EntityType

```
<!--Errors Found During Generation:
  warning 6002: The table/view 'xxx.x_map' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.
  -->
```

Changing the DB schema to have the correct PKs and updating the the EDMX fixed the issue in my case.

Hope this goes some way towards you fixing your issue.